# Rescale circle view at zoom gesture

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, pinchzoom

I have an UIView that represents a circle. When the user is performing the zoom gesture, i want to resize the circle, but maintain the same center of it, only resize the width and height of it. If the zoom scale is large, the user will only see the circle when he zooms in that area, so i want to resize it accordingly so that the other elements in view still be visible and the circle ratio to maintain the same even though the zoom scale is 1 or 10.

Comment: so you're changing the view frame? i don't understand what you're saying with the second half of the question...

Comment: When the user is zooming in, i want to decrease the size of the circle view, and when the user is zooming out, to increase it's size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to take the current `frame` and use the zoom factor  (delta since the last change) with `CGRectInset`. It will create a larger or smaller version of the `frame` without changing the centre point.

Comment: I don't think i'm doing it right Wain.

 if(self.lastScale != zoomScale)
    {
        CGFloat delta = zoomScale - self.lastScale;
        CGRectInset(_pointA.frame, delta, delta);
        
        self.lastScale = zoomScale;
    }

Comment: `CGRectInset` creates a new rect for you, but you need to set it as the new frame

Comment: Yes, i saw it after i posted. Thank you!